# Well definedness of the map $M\times A/{\frak a} \to M/{\frak a}M,\ (m, a+{\frak a}) \mapsto am + {\frak a}M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, tensor-products

I recently did the exercise proving that $$M\otimes A/{\frak a} \cong M/{\frak a}M$$

When i did the proof the first time, i defined the map

$$\varphi\colon M\times A/{\frak a} \to M/{\frak a}M,\ (m, a+{\frak a}) \mapsto am + {\frak a}M$$

However, i just realized that the last time i did this, i forgot to check whether this map is actually well defined. So this time i tried the following:

In order to prove this map is independend of the choice of representatives, let's suppose $a'$ and $a$ are two representatives of the same class, that is:

$$a+{\frak a} = a'+{\frak a}$$

Then we have $$\varphi(m,(a'-a)+{\frak a}) = (a'-a)m +{\frak a}M$$

Since $(a'-a) \in \frak a$ by assumption, $(a'-a)m \in {\frak a}M$ and therefore

$$(a'-a)m +{\frak a}M = {\frak a}M$$

---

### My questions:

I could now finish the argument saying that since $\varphi(m,(a'-a)+{\frak a})$ maps in to the neutral element in ${\frak a}M$, we can conclude that

$$\varphi(m,a'+{\frak a}) = \varphi(m, a+{\frak a}M)$$

However, if i'm not missing anything, i'm implicitely assuming bilinearity. Is that correct?

The issue i am having is that if i would assume bilinearity of $\varphi$, this proof would be pretty straight forward. But i'm feeling quite uncomfortable showing that $\varphi$ satisfies bilinearity before even knowing whether this map is well-defined.

So in fact my questions are

### Question 1:

Is my attempt even correct or did i do errors?

### Question 2:

Is it even reasonable to confirm $\varphi$ satisfies bilinearity prior to knowing if $\varphi$ is even well defined?

What would be the correct approach to this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're right that your current formulation is a little fishy. Instead, compute $\varphi(m,a+ \mathfrak{a})$ and $\varphi(m,a' + \mathfrak{a})$ and check that these coincide (which is basically what you have done).

Comment: Thanks for the advise @QiZhu. Highly appreciated.